# Screen session used to run python PFA on server dies after a few days

Tags: server, ssh, python, gnu-screen

I am running a python based PFA script which basically writes spreadsheets after every hour. It is working well. I use SSH on Putty to access my server and hence I used a screen session to run the script in the background. It works well for a few days and then dies out of sudden. Right now, it ran for 6 days in a row and died after. 
Using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial) on Digital Ocean.

I used -

> screen python we.py

I tried finding if there is something which might help me from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Commands).
Do I need to assign any name to the screen using -S to avoid this ? Or do I have to reattach it everyday using -x or -p to keep it live ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle your problem:

### Run the task as a systemd service

It sounds like this is a long running task that should actually be a service that gets started on boot, gets restarted by the init system when it fails and should have a proper logging to journald.

To make this happen, follow these steps:

Create a file `/lib/systemd/system/python-we.service` and insert the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python We Job
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /full/path/to/we.py

# Make sure stderr/stdout is captured in the systemd journal.
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After creating the file, run the following commands to register the `python-we.service` file to systemd, enable it (to make it start after a reboot) and finally start it.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable python-we
systemctl start python-we
```

If you use systemd you can read the logs via `journalctl -u python-we`.

### Run it in screen (not recommended)

Start a screen session (just type `screen`) and in this screen session start your job. This way the screen session only exists if you close the shell inside the screen session and you can observe the logs inside the screen session.

As I said: This is not a recommended way to run a service since it's kind of hacky. Your screen session will bloat and the service won't be automatically restartet in case it fails.

Comment: After a few minutes of fidgeting I was able to get it running as a service.

Comment: Cool! You’re doing the right thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

The program you are running inside screen is probably exiting, when this happens the session will close and you will loose all console output and the status code.

If you really want to keep using screen for this, I'd suggest pressing `ctrl-a` then `shift-h` before disconnecting from screen to log the session. A file called `screenlog.0` will be created in the working directory that contains all console output, hopefully that can tell you why your program is exiting.